# How to show there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(t,x)-f(s,x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in [c,d]$ and for all $t\in (s-\delta,s+\delta)$?

Tags: analysis

Suppose $f:(a,b)\times [c,d]\to \Bbb R$ is a continuous function, how to prove the following conclusion?

$\forall s\in (a,b),\forall \epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(t,x)-f(s,x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in [c,d]$ and for all $t\in (s-\delta,s+\delta)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is uniformly continuous on the compact set $[a+\epsilon, b-\epsilon] \times [c,d]$ (assuming that $\epsilon <(b-a)/2$). Your statement follows immediately from this. [ Choose $\delta$ as in definition of uniformly continuity and just make sure that $(s-\delta, s+\delta) \subset [a+\epsilon, b-\epsilon]$].